# pnmtopnm: command not found

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation, cinnamon

Does anyone know how to install pnmtopnm? I installed `ivtools-bin` and `netpbm` but none of these packages provide it. This is what I get after running `pnmtopnm`:

```
No command 'pnmtopnm' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pnmtopgm' from package 'ivtools-bin' (universe)
 Command 'pnmtopng' from package 'netpbm' (main)
 Command 'pngtopnm' from package 'netpbm' (main)
pnmtopnm: command not found
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install netpbm-progs
```

but it says `Unable to locate package netpbm-progs`

I use Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64-bit (Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca)

Any support is appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

`pnmtoplainpnm` replaces `pnmtopnm -plain`, here the link: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pnmtoplainpnm. Whole story here:

```
pnmtoplainpnm(1) - Linux man page
Name
pnmtoplainpnm - replaced by pnmtopnm
Description
This program is part of Netpbm(1).

pnmtoplainpnm was obsoleted in Netpbm 10.23 (July 2004) by pnmtopnm(1).JustusetheNetpbmcommonoption -plain.

pnmtoplainpnm exists today for backward compatibility; all it does is call pnmtopnm -plain.

pnmtoplainpnm was new in Netpbm 8.2 (March 2000) as a renaming of pnmnoraw, which was new in Pbmplus in November 1989.
Referenced By
pamslice(1), pnmnoraw(1), ppmtoarbtxt(1)
```